# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.' when trying to launch a shortcut

Tags: c#, process, process.start

I have been trying to launch Microsoft Teams through C#, by launching the shortcut.

However I am getting an error:

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'`

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace OnlineLearning
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo teams = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\cesq\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Teams.lnk");
            teams.CreateNoWindow = true;
            teams.RedirectStandardError = true;
            teams.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            teams.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            Process foo = Process.Start(teams);
        }
    }
}
```

I have been following an example from this question: [Run an application via shortcut using Process.Start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141821/run-an-application-via-shortcut-using-process-start)

And did as one answer suggested:

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\cesq\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Teams.lnk";
        proc.Start();
```

Sadly this didn't work (gave the same error).

Also the accepted answer:

*Setting `UseShellExecute = false` was the problem. Once I removed that, it stopped crashing.*

Didn't work for me, since I already have done what it suggested.

Also this question: [How to run a shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980637/how-to-run-a-shortcut)
did not help me as well, as it is not relevant to my example.

As well as this one: ['The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102696/the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-application-for-this-os-platform)

Now I am out of ideas, so I am asking for your help.

Comment: Did you see the comment on that answer?  *"This is even more important now because .NET core has changed the default of this property to false. I was running into this when I wasn't setting this property at all. – 
Cdaragorn"* Looks like you need to set it to `true`, whereas the solution was to leave it as its  default, which is different now.

Comment: @madreflection Did like you suggested, gives `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.'`

Comment: Do you *really* need to redirect the IO streams? Highly doubtful. Don't set those to true.

Comment: @madreflection, Ok I googled the error and found an answer. Needed to set it to true, but also to set `teams.RedirectStandardOutput` to `false` and remove `teams.RedirectStandardInput` and `teams.RedirectStandardError` .

Comment: I don't think you need to set them at all. Redirection of IO streams is opt-in.

Comment: @madreflection You are correct, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run an application via shortcut using Process.Start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141821/run-an-application-via-shortcut-using-process-start)

Comment: I've flagged it as a duplicate of the question you linked because the answer was there all along.